# Extending core block product_list_toolbar is not working

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, blocks, extend

I am trying to override a core block using the code below. I haven't located any extensions that are already extending this core block but could that be the problem?

config.xml

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_list_toolbar>Mine_Sliderview_Block_Product_List_Toolbar</product_list_toolbar>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

/app/code/local/Mine/Sliderview/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

```
<?php 
class Mine_Sliderview_Block_Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar {
/**
 * Products collection
 *
 * @var Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
 */
protected $_collection = null;

/**
 * GET parameter page variable
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_pageVarName     = 'p';

/** 
* --Added by tyler
* Add get Parameter filterByLetter variable
*/
protected $_filterByLetterVarName = "filterByLetter";

/**
 * GET parameter order variable
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_orderVarName        = 'order';

/**
 * GET parameter direction variable
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_directionVarName    = 'dir';

/**
 * GET parameter mode variable
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_modeVarName         = 'mode';

/**
 * GET parameter limit variable
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_limitVarName        = 'limit';

/**
 * List of available order fields
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_availableOrder      = array();

/**
 * List of available view types
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_availableMode       = array();

/**
 * Is enable View switcher
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_enableViewSwitcher  = true;

/**
 * Is Expanded
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_isExpanded          = true;

/**
 * Default Order field
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_orderField          = null;

/**
 * Default direction
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_direction           = 'asc';

/**
 * Default View mode
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_viewMode            = null;

/**
 * Available page limits for different list modes
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_availableLimit  = array();

/**
 * Default limits per page
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_defaultAvailableLimit  = array(10=>10,20=>20,50=>50);

/**
 * @var bool $_paramsMemorizeAllowed
 */
protected $_paramsMemorizeAllowed = true;

/**
 * Retrieve Catalog Config object
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Config
 */
protected function _getConfig()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config');
}

/**
 * Init Toolbar
 *
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_orderField  = Mage::getStoreConfig(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Config::XML_PATH_LIST_DEFAULT_SORT_BY
    );

    $this->_availableOrder = $this->_getConfig()->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();

    switch (Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_mode')) {
        case 'slider':
            $this->_availableMode = array('slider' => $this->__('Slider'));
            break;

        case 'grid':
            $this->_availableMode = array('grid' => $this->__('Grid'));
            break;

        case 'list':
            $this->_availableMode = array('list' => $this->__('List'));
            break;

        case 'grid-list':
            $this->_availableMode = array('grid' => $this->__('Grid'), 'list' =>  $this->__('List'));
            break;

        case 'list-grid':
            $this->_availableMode = array('list' => $this->__('List'), 'grid' => $this->__('Grid'));
            break;

        case 'slider-grid-list':
            $this->_availableMode = array('slider' => $this->__('Slider'), 'grid' => $this->__('Grid'), 'list' => $this->__('List'));
            break;
    }
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml');
}

/**
 * Disable list state params memorizing
 */
public function disableParamsMemorizing()
{
    $this->_paramsMemorizeAllowed = false;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Memorize parameter value for session
 *
 * @param string $param parameter name
 * @param mixed $value parameter value
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
protected function _memorizeParam($param, $value)
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session');
    if ($this->_paramsMemorizeAllowed && !$session->getParamsMemorizeDisabled()) {
        $session->setData($param, $value);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set collection to pager
 *
 * @param Varien_Data_Collection $collection
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
        $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Return products collection instance
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
 */
public function getCollection()
{
    return $this->_collection;
}

/**
 * Getter for $_pageVarName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPageVarName()
{
    return $this->_pageVarName;
}

/**
 * Retrieve order field GET var name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getOrderVarName()
{
    return $this->_orderVarName;
}

/**
 * Retrieve sort direction GET var name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDirectionVarName()
{
    return $this->_directionVarName;
}

/**
 * Retrieve view mode GET var name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getModeVarName()
{
    return $this->_modeVarName;
}

/**
 * Getter for $_limitVarName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLimitVarName()
{
    return $this->_limitVarName;
}

/**
 * Return current page from request
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getCurrentPage()
{
    if ($page = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getPageVarName())) {
        return $page;
    }
    return 1;
}

/**
 * Get grit products sort order field
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCurrentOrder()
{
    $order = $this->_getData('_current_grid_order');
    if ($order) {
        return $order;
    }

    $orders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
    $defaultOrder = $this->_orderField;

    if (!isset($orders[$defaultOrder])) {
        $keys = array_keys($orders);
        $defaultOrder = $keys[0];
    }

    $order = $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getOrderVarName());
    if ($order && isset($orders[$order])) {
        if ($order == $defaultOrder) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsSortOrder();
        } else {
            $this->_memorizeParam('sort_order', $order);
        }
    } else {
        $order = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortOrder();
    }
    // validate session value
    if (!$order || !isset($orders[$order])) {
        $order = $defaultOrder;
    }
    $this->setData('_current_grid_order', $order);
    return $order;
}

/**
 * Retrieve current direction
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCurrentDirection()
{
    $dir = $this->_getData('_current_grid_direction');
    if ($dir) {
        return $dir;
    }

    $directions = array('asc', 'desc');
    $dir = strtolower($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getDirectionVarName()));
    if ($dir && in_array($dir, $directions)) {
        if ($dir == $this->_direction) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsSortDirection();
        } else {
            $this->_memorizeParam('sort_direction', $dir);
        }
    } else {
        $dir = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getSortDirection();
    }
    // validate direction
    if (!$dir || !in_array($dir, $directions)) {
        $dir = $this->_direction;
    }
    $this->setData('_current_grid_direction', $dir);
    return $dir;
}

/**
 * Set default Order field
 *
 * @param string $field
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function setDefaultOrder($field)
{
    if (isset($this->_availableOrder[$field])) {
        $this->_orderField = $field;
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set default sort direction
 *
 * @param string $dir
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function setDefaultDirection($dir)
{
    if (in_array(strtolower($dir), array('asc', 'desc'))) {
        $this->_direction = strtolower($dir);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrieve available Order fields list
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAvailableOrders()
{
    return $this->_availableOrder;
}

/**
 * Set Available order fields list
 *
 * @param array $orders
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function setAvailableOrders($orders)
{
    $this->_availableOrder = $orders;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add order to available orders
 *
 * @param string $order
 * @param string $value
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function addOrderToAvailableOrders($order, $value)
{
    $this->_availableOrder[$order] = $value;
    return $this;
}
/**
 * Remove order from available orders if exists
 *
 * @param string $order
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function removeOrderFromAvailableOrders($order)
{
    if (isset($this->_availableOrder[$order])) {
        unset($this->_availableOrder[$order]);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Compare defined order field vith current order field
 *
 * @param string $order
 * @return bool
 */
public function isOrderCurrent($order)
{
    return ($order == $this->getCurrentOrder());
}

/**
 * Retrieve Pager URL
 *
 * @param string $order
 * @param string $direction
 * @return string
 */
public function getOrderUrl($order, $direction)
{
    if (is_null($order)) {
        $order = $this->getCurrentOrder() ? $this->getCurrentOrder() : $this->_availableOrder[0];
    }
    return $this->getPagerUrl(array(
        $this->getOrderVarName()=>$order,
        $this->getDirectionVarName()=>$direction,
        $this->getPageVarName() => null
    ));
}

/**
 * Return current URL with rewrites and additional parameters
 *
 * @param array $params Query parameters
 * @return string
 */
public function getPagerUrl($params=array())
{
    $urlParams = array();
    $urlParams['_current']  = true;
    $urlParams['_escape']   = true;
    $urlParams['_use_rewrite']   = true;
    $urlParams['_query']    = $params;
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/*', $urlParams);
}

/**
 * Retrieve current View mode
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCurrentMode()
{
    $mode = $this->_getData('_current_grid_mode');
    if ($mode) {
        return $mode;
    }
    $modes = array_keys($this->_availableMode);
    $defaultMode = current($modes);
    $mode = $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getModeVarName());
    if ($mode) {
        if ($mode == $defaultMode) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsDisplayMode();
        } else {
            $this->_memorizeParam('display_mode', $mode);
        }
    } else {
        $mode = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getDisplayMode();
    }

    if (!$mode || !isset($this->_availableMode[$mode])) {
        $mode = $defaultMode;
    }
    $this->setData('_current_grid_mode', $mode);
    return $mode;
}

/**
 * Compare defined view mode with current active mode
 *
 * @param string $mode
 * @return bool
 */
public function isModeActive($mode)
{
    return $this->getCurrentMode() == $mode;
}

/**
 * Retrieve availables view modes
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getModes()
{
    return $this->_availableMode;
}

/**
 * Set available view modes list
 *
 * @param array $modes
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function setModes($modes)
{
    if(!isset($this->_availableMode)){
        $this->_availableMode = $modes;
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrive URL for view mode
 *
 * @param string $mode
 * @return string
 */
public function getModeUrl($mode)
{
    return $this->getPagerUrl( array($this->getModeVarName()=>$mode, $this->getPageVarName() => null) );
}

/**
 * Disable view switcher
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function disableViewSwitcher()
{
    $this->_enableViewSwitcher = false;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Enable view switcher
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function enableViewSwitcher()
{
    $this->_enableViewSwitcher = true;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Is a enabled view switcher
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEnabledViewSwitcher()
{
    return $this->_enableViewSwitcher;
}

/**
 * Disable Expanded
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function disableExpanded()
{
    $this->_isExpanded = false;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Enable Expanded
 *
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function enableExpanded()
{
    $this->_isExpanded = true;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Check is Expanded
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isExpanded()
{
    return $this->_isExpanded;
}

/**
 * Retrieve default per page values
 *
 * @return string (comma separated)
 */
public function getDefaultPerPageValue()
{
    if ($this->getCurrentMode() == 'list') {
        if ($default = $this->getDefaultListPerPage()) {
            return $default;
        }
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_per_page');
    }
    elseif ($this->getCurrentMode() == 'grid') {
        if ($default = $this->getDefaultGridPerPage()) {
            return $default;
        }
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
    }
    elseif ($this->getCurrentMode() == 'slider') {
        if ($default = $this->getDefaultSliderPerPage()) {
            return $default;
        }
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/slider_per_page');
    }
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Add new limit to pager for mode
 *
 * @param string $mode
 * @param string $value
 * @param string $label
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
 */
public function addPagerLimit($mode, $value, $label='')
{
    if (!isset($this->_availableLimit[$mode])) {
        $this->_availableLimit[$mode] = array();
    }
    $this->_availableLimit[$mode][$value] = empty($label) ? $value : $label;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Retrieve available limits for current view mode
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAvailableLimit()
{
    $currentMode = $this->getCurrentMode(); 
    if (in_array($currentMode, array('list', 'grid', 'slider'))) {
        return $this->_getAvailableLimit($currentMode);
    } else {
        return $this->_defaultAvailableLimit;
    }
}

/**
 * Retrieve available limits for specified view mode
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getAvailableLimit($mode)
{  
    if (isset($this->_availableLimit[$mode])) {  
        return $this->_availableLimit[$mode];
    } 
    $perPageConfigKey = 'catalog/frontend/' . $mode . '_per_page_values';
    $perPageValues = (string)Mage::getStoreConfig($perPageConfigKey);
    $perPageValues = explode(',', $perPageValues);
    $perPageValues = array_combine($perPageValues, $perPageValues);
    if (Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('catalog/frontend/list_allow_all')) {
        return ($perPageValues + array('all'=>$this->__('All')));
    } else {
        return $perPageValues;
    }
}

/**
 * Get specified products limit display per page
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLimit()
{
    $limit = $this->_getData('_current_limit');
    if ($limit) {
        return $limit;
    }

    $limits = $this->getAvailableLimit();
    $defaultLimit = $this->getDefaultPerPageValue();
    if (!$defaultLimit || !isset($limits[$defaultLimit])) { 
        $keys = array_keys($limits);
        $defaultLimit = $keys[0];
    }

    $limit = $this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getLimitVarName());
    if ($limit && isset($limits[$limit])) {  
        if ($limit == $defaultLimit) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsLimitPage();
        } else { 
            $this->_memorizeParam('limit_page', $limit);
        }
    } else {
        $limit = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLimitPage();
    }
    if (!$limit || !isset($limits[$limit])) {
        $limit = $defaultLimit;
    }

    $this->setData('_current_limit', $limit);
    return $limit;
}

/**
 * Retrieve Limit Pager URL
 *
 * @param int $limit
 * @return string
 */
public function getLimitUrl($limit)
{
    return $this->getPagerUrl(array(
        $this->getLimitVarName() => $limit,
        $this->getPageVarName() => null
    ));
}

public function isLimitCurrent($limit)
{
    return $limit == $this->getLimit();
}

public function getFirstNum()
{
    $collection = $this->getCollection();
    return $collection->getPageSize()*($collection->getCurPage()-1)+1;
}

public function getLastNum()
{
    $collection = $this->getCollection();
    return $collection->getPageSize()*($collection->getCurPage()-1)+$collection->count();
}

public function getTotalNum()
{
    return $this->getCollection()->getSize();
}

public function isFirstPage()
{
    return $this->getCollection()->getCurPage() == 1;
}

public function getLastPageNum()
{
    return $this->getCollection()->getLastPageNumber();
}

/**
 * Render pagination HTML
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPagerHtml()
{
    $pagerBlock = $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager');

    if ($pagerBlock instanceof Varien_Object) {

        /* @var $pagerBlock Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager */
        $pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit($this->getAvailableLimit());

        $pagerBlock->setUseContainer(false)
            ->setShowPerPage(false)
            ->setShowAmounts(false)
            ->setLimitVarName($this->getLimitVarName())
            ->setPageVarName($this->getPageVarName())
            ->setLimit($this->getLimit())
            ->setFrameLength(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame'))
            ->setJump(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/pagination/pagination_frame_skip'))
            ->setCollection($this->getCollection());

        return $pagerBlock->toHtml();
    }

    return '';
}
}
```

Comment: You have `/app/code/local/Mine/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`.  Is it really there or is it `/app/code/local/Mine/Sliderview/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. It is `/app/code/local/Monin/Sliderview/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php`

Comment: Make sure you have disabled the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me.  Make sure your extension is enabled in `app/etc/modules/Monin_Sliderview.xml`

One more thing, if that's your entire `config.xml` don't forget to enclose all of it in `<config></config>`